# How to view and handle hidden data in variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging, lua

How do I view and extract data inside a variable, populated from another piece of code, that may contain hidden escape characters or data in Javascript (JQuery stuff is fine too)?

For example lets say I have an Ajax call such as this, where data is printed from a back-end script written in Lua:

```
success: function(data)
{
    dataItems = data.split(",");
}
```

Lets say I'm expecting a four letter string in each of the dataItems array. If I use Chrome or Firefox putting a breakpoint on dataItems I see each array containing a four letter string and I'm happy because it looks right and I can now process it. However if I do a `print(dataItems[1].length)` for example I notice it has a length of 5, and my debugger shows `dataItems[1]="abcd"`, obviously there is something hidden inside it that doesn't show easily as part of the arrays variable. Is there a better way to catch and view these hidden pieces of information preferably in a browser debugger? How does one go about removing this undesired data once it is recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's surrounded with empty spaces.
Try:

```
console.log(dataItems[1].trim().length);
```

Comment: This does work! Is there a better way to identify this in the common browsers debuggers?

Comment: It's an empty space, you won't see that. What I normally do is try highlighting(selecting) the text in the console. :)